# Using Apache Camel's ConsumerTemplate and ProducerTemplate in clean Camel application

Tags: apache-camel

Are there any real use cases for ConsumerTemplate and ProducerTemplate in a pure, "native" (i.e. no Spring Boot, etc.) Camel application?

Apart from tests, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, say we need to send some message to an Kafka topic and there is some processor which will process the message and send the response to another topic which needs to be consumed by camel. The flow is like,

client -> send request -> camel sender route (thread 1) -> kafka in topic (and ACK goes back to client) -> processing in separate java process -> response in kafka out topic -> camel consumer route (thread 2) -> response to client

Certainly one approach can be creating 2 routes as above, but what if the client needs a synchronous response i.e. only thread 1 will perform everything?

A possible solution can be making the sender route (thread 1) to wait for the response from kafka (may be, adding a **consumer at the end of sender route**) and then return back to client from the same route.

Does it make sense?